# Is it possible to limit export feature class in ArcSDE to only some users?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, security

I'm trying to manage user and their privileges in ArcSDE and sql server 2012. I can privilege the select and edit a layer for users. I can use just two privileges but i want to permit export feature class capability for some users.Is it possible to permit and revoke export feature class for users ?

Comment: This is often asked, and simply not possible. Any user with SELECT access can export data in a multitude of ways.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible but not easy. you should write custom ArcObject code to disable any tool or command that exports feature data. And off course you should manage users with a custom user manager application to set their permissions (enable/disable feature export)

Comment: This will **not** prevent export, just make it slightly more difficult.

Comment: Off course Many other things must be disabled too, like, Python window, model builder, search dockable window. But it is possible to prevent the export. Vince, I've done this before!

Comment: And you'll need to eliminate access to the database client from anything but ArcGIS, and to prevent the user from downloading any application which could access the database directly,...  In fact, you *can't* prevent a determined user with SELECT permission from accessing the database rows and writing them to ASCII. You can strip all access except though proxies, but then users are unlikely to be able to accomplish necessary tasks, and still an experienced user could use the image service for heads-up digitizing.

Comment: @FaridCher I don't want to use Arcobject solution.Thanks anayway